# How can I check if a date field is in ISO format?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, iso

Using Python, is there a way check if a `date` field of a document in a MongoDB collection is in ISO format or in string format?

Answer (score 12):

You can make use of `fromisoformat` method in `datetime` library.

```
from datetime import date

try:
    date.fromisoformat(date_string)
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid isoformat string")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert a datetime object into a .isoformat() string in Python. The other direction is a bit harder but works as well. Use these code snippets. If they return a datetime object you can be happy.

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

then...

```
import datetime
import dateutil.parser

def getDateTimeFromISO8601String(s):
    d = dateutil.parser.parse(s)
    return d
```

Check also:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

[How to convert python .isoformat() string back into datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331512/how-to-convert-python-isoformat-string-back-into-datetime-object)

Answer (score 1):

From what I recall, an ISO format is a string so I would do something like:

```
if len(date.split('-')) == 3: # check if the len is 3. 
    print('ISO string format')
else:
    print('String format')
```

Comment: `len(date.split('-') == 3)` should be `len(date.split('-')) == 3`.  It may get edited before you see the comment.

Answer (score -2):

You can use something like the following statement:

```
if variable_name is str:
    print('string format!')
else:
    print('not a string!')
```

Comment: you can print the information and then check if the date is formatted in accordance with the ISO standard(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).