# Store datetime in a CouchDB data model

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, datetime, couchdb

To save some sensor data on a RPI in CouchDB using `pycouchdb`, I created a database model class to have a clear structure instead of loosely typed dicts

```
class SensorMeasure(NamedTuple):
  temp: float
  soilMoisture: float
  dateTime: datetime
```

Since it seems not possible to serialize this object automatically, I used the [`_asdict()` method from `NamedTuple`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35282286/3276634) to get an dict object, which could be stored in the database

```
server = pycouchdb.Server("http://127.0.0.1:5984/")
db = server.database(dbName)
measure = SensorMeasure(temp=sensor.getTemperature(), soilMoisture = sensor.getMoisture(), dateTime = datetime.now())
db.save(measure._asdict())
```

While this works well for primitive types like float, it breaks on `datetime`:

```
TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable
```

It seems like that I have to [tell the serializer how he could generate a string from the `datetime` object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable), which seems not possible for me without modifing [`pycouchdbs` source code](https://github.com/histrio/py-couchdb/blob/164fe373a3d41c539ec1f42915251d726a23c12a/pycouchdb/client.py#L372).

The only working workaround seems using `string` instead of `datetime` in the `SensorMeasure` model and use the `isoformat()` method of `datetime`. But this would require me to

1. [install additional libraries for parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28334064/3276634)
2. I have to parse it on every usage with the overhead of creating a new object, specify the format, ...

In terms of design, it would be much better to have a `datetime` attribute in the class. How can I archive this?

#### Other workaround thoughts

With the `zip` function it seems possible to define which keys should be serialized. This leads me to the idea of removing the `dateTime` field and then re-adding it as string value like this:

```
class SensorMeasure(NamedTuple):
  temp:float
  soilMoisture: float
  dateTime: datetime

  def test(self):
    serializeFields = list(self._fields)
    del serializeFields['dateTime']

    serialized = OrderedDict(zip(serializeFields, self))
    print(serialized)

    serialized['dateTime'] = dateTime.isoformat()
    print(serialized)
```

But this doesn't work since the returned tuple is immutable. Converting it to a list should allow writing, however the lists seems only allowing integer keys:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 0):

### Suboptimal workaround

**This is just for documentation purpose/completeness. Scroll down for a better solution**

With a few converting operations, the workaround idea from my question works:

```
class SensorMeasure(NamedTuple):
  temp: float
  soilMoisture: float
  dateTime: datetime

  def test(self):
    serializeFields = list(self._fields)
    del serializeFields[serializeFields.index('dateTime')]

    serialized = OrderedDict(zip(serializeFields, self))
    tmp = list(serialized.items())
    tmp.append(('dateTime', self.dateTime.isoformat()))

    finalDict = OrderedDict(tmp)
    return finalDict
```

But it is not only a lot of code/work for datetime serialization, which is required in every model. Or at least a call in every model to some helper class.

#### Better solution: Custom `db.save` method

A better solution would be setting default parsing method on `json.dumps`

```
jsonStr = json.dumps(doc, default = str)
```

Sadly `pycouchdb` currently [doesn't allow this](https://github.com/histrio/py-couchdb/blob/164fe373a3d41c539ec1f42915251d726a23c12a/pycouchdb/client.py#L372). Of course I can send pull request that extend this functionality by e.g. a new parameter. But for now, I just create my own save method as a quick and suiteable fix.

```
def save(sensorMeasure):
  doc = copy.deepcopy(sensorMeasure._asdict())
  doc['_id'] = uuid.uuid4().hex

  # Default is important to parse datetime objects
  jsonStr = json.dumps(doc, default = str)
  data = pycouchdb.utils.force_bytes(jsonStr)
  (resp, results) = db.resource(doc['_id']).put(data=data)
```

The only problem being still present is the lack of typing when using `db.get()`:

```
doc = db.get("bb29e02dc2364a57ac1e707d7dc2134b")
```

This returns an dictionary, so parsing the string to a datetime object is still required. It could be done using a [constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1305663/3276634). Not as easy as I know it e.g. from ASP.NET Core, where serialization/deserialization could be done with a single line of code, but seems possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define your own decoder/encoder. I did this, works fine for saving:

```
import json
import couchdb
from datetime import datetime, date

class JSONEncoderExtendDate(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return obj.isoformat()
        elif isinstance(obj, date):
            return obj.isoformat()


        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

def encode_json(obj):
    return json.dumps(obj, cls=JSONEncoderExtendDate)
def decode_json(obj):
    return json.loads(obj)


couchdb.json.use(decode=decode_json, encode=encode_json)
```

And then just do your save normally.

Probably should have also implemented the decoder, but that is pretty obvious. I only use saving at the python side. You need to define both the decoder and encoder, that is why it's not empty.