# How can I log a dictionary into a log file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, python-logging

I have a dictionary:

```
 d = {name : "John", age: 10}.
```

And a log file setup as:

```
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG, filename = "sample.log")
```

Is it possible to log this dictionary into the "sample.log" file? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: I have to log into the same file...as there are other logs also being logged.

Answer (score 64):

### Simple solution that works

The logging functions will convert the `'%s'` to string representation (and if the object happens to be a container, then `repr()` will be used for the contained objects)

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='sample.log')
logging.debug('Sample dict log: %s', {'name' : "John", 'age': 10})
```

How it shows in the log file:

```
DEBUG:root:Sample dict log: {'age': 10, 'name': 'John'}
```

If you have custom objects (e.g. instances of your own classes), you should implement a sensible `__str__` and/or `__repr__` for it, and the above will work without any hacks.

More on this here [What is the difference between __str__ and __repr__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

### A Note on performance

Notice that

`logging.debug('%s', some_dict)` is not same as

`logging.debug('{0}'.format(some_dict))`

In the first one, the function is passed 2 arguments `'%s'` and the original `some_dict`.

In the second one, the function is passed one argument which is the already-converted `some_dict` to a string.
Because a function needs the arguments evaluated, the second example will always do the conversion, even if logging configs have turned off the logging of debug messages.

That's an unnecessary performance penalty.
In the the first example, the `logging.debug` function can decide to do the conversion, or not.

### JSON is not very good for this

For objects that aren't JSON-like (object instances, datetime, etc), `json.dumps()` would require a custom serializer e.g. with `datetime` objects you get:

`TypeError: datetime.datetime(...) is not JSON serializable`

This goes for any type that isn't supported by `json.dumps()`

Whereas the `logging` module would figure out a good representation for the object

Comment: You can coerce types which are not handled by json.dumps() using json hooks as in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793448/how-to-convert-to-a-python-datetime-object-with-json-loads

Comment: On Raspberry Pi this only worked when the dictionary did not contain certain information. Seems the pprint solution universal.

Answer (score 14):

Simple you can use

```
dict_data = {"test":"data"}
logger.info("Loging dict ---> {0}".format(dict_data))
```

Comment: I wouldn't do this.  It's bad practice to format things in loggers because the format will always be evaluated.  If your dict is massive and you have logLevel set to `ERROR`, the dict will still be converted to a string despite not being printed anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

you can convert it to string:

```
string_dictionary = str(d)
```

and then log the string dictionary variable to the file

using JSON

```
import json

d = {"name":"John","age":10}
json_string = json.dumps(d)
```

and if you want to convert the string back:

```
d = json.loads(json_string)
```

Comment: is it a good idea to convert it into a string and then store it ?

Comment: the logging file is a text file so whatever the method you will follow to log it, it will ends with converting the dictionary to string
and the second way is to convert it to json if you want to use it again 
for json it will be json.dumps(d)
offcourse after importing json

Comment: yea...i was looking for json.dumps Can you show a sample for the code above ??

Comment: sure,
import json
d = {"name":"John","age":10}
json_string = json.dumps(d)
and if you want to convert the string back:
d = json.loads(json_string)

Comment: so then i can directly put json_string into log files??

Answer (score 4):

The problem with `str(dictionary)` and `json.dumps(dictionary)` is that the output can human unfriendly, especially if the dictionary is big and has nested structures.

If that's the case, you can Python's built-in `pprint` to pretty format the dictionary before logging:

```py
import pprint

my_complex_dict = pprint.pformat(my_complex_dict)
logger.info(f"My complex dict:\n{my_complex_dict}")
```

Comment: Not sure if there was this option back in 2016, but now you can simply add `indent` parameter to json.dumps and you'll get nicely formated dictionary. Check [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Answer (score 1):

I came to this question when I wanted to log JSON lines for Cloudwatch.

I ended up using [`python-json-logger`](https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger).

Install it: `pip install python-json-logger`

Use `pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter` as the formatter class.