# More elegant and efficient way to iterate through a nested dict?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

There are 2 dicts of params:

```
fb_config = {
  "page_likes" : {
    "page_id": "1111",
                       "metric": "page_fans",
                       "since": "2019-01-01 00:00:00",
                       "until": "2019-01-01 00:00:00",
                       "date_preset" : "yesterday",
                       "period": "day"},

    "page_impressions" : {"page_id": "1111",
                       "metric": "page_impressions",
                       "since": "yesterday",
                       "until": "yesterday",
                       "date_preset" : "yesterday",
                       "period": "day"},

    "page_engaged_users" : {"page_id": "1111",
                       "metric": "page_engaged_users",
                       "since": "today",
                       "until": "today",
                       "date_preset" : "yesterday",
                       "period": "day"}}
```

and

```
ga_config =

{

'view_id_123': {'view_id': '123',
                           'start_date': "2019-01-01 00:00:00",
                           'end_date': "2019-01-01 00:00:00",
                           'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}, {'expression':'ga:pageviews'}, {'expression':'ga:users'}, {'expression':'ga:bounces'},
                          {'expression':'ga:avgSessionDuration'}],
                           'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:year'}, {'name': 'ga:userType'}, {'name': 'ga:sessionCount'}, {'name': 'ga:browser'},
                                          {'name': 'ga:source'}]},

'view_id_456': {'view_id': '456',
                           'start_date': "today",
                           'end_date': "today",
                           'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:bounces'}, {'expression':'ga:users'}],
                           'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:mobileDeviceModel'}, {'name': 'ga:dataSource'}]},

'view_id_789': {'view_id': '789',
                           'start_date': "yesterday",
                           'end_date': "yesterday",
                           'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:bounces'}, {'expression':'ga:users'}],
                           'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:mobileDeviceModel'}, {'name': 'ga:dataSource'}]}

}
```

In the code I can't keep the params and want to pull them from a json file. After loading the file all the dates have to be converted from str to datetime format.

This process is accomlished through several loops:

```
for values in params.values():
    if 'since' in values:
        if values['since'] == 'today':
            values['since'] = datetime.now()
        elif values['since'] == 'yesterday':
            values['since'] = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
        else: 
            values['since'] = dt.datetime.strptime(values['since'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

for values in params.values():
    if 'until' in y:
        if values['until'] == 'today':
            values['until'] = datetime.now()
        elif values['until'] == 'yesterday':
            values['until'] = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
        else:
            values['until'] = dt.datetime.strptime(y['until'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

for values in params.values():
    if 'start_date' in values:
        if values['start_date'] == 'today':
            values['start_date'] = datetime.now()
        elif values['start_date'] == 'yesterday':
            values['start_date'] = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
        else:
            values['start_date'] = dt.datetime.strptime(values['start_date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

for values in params.values():
    if 'end_date' in values:
        if values['end_date'] == 'today':
            values['end_date'] = datetime.now()
        elif values['end_date'] == 'yesterday':
            values['end_date'] = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
        else:
            values['end_date'] = dt.datetime.strptime(values['end_date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

But the code is really ugly and DRY is violated. Are there better ways to iterate through nested dics and change the values of the certain keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit more compact:

```
for values in params.values():
    for k in ('since','until','start_date','end_date'):
        if k in values:
            if values[k] == 'today':
                values[k] = datetime.now()
            elif values[k] == 'yesterday':
                values[k] = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
            else: 
                values[k] = dt.datetime.strptime(values[k], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Python developer, but I can see that you are looping 4 times over the same data, when you should do it only once:

```py
def formatDate(value, default):
    if value == 'today':
        date = datetime.now()
    elif value == 'yesterday':
        date = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
    else:
        date = default

    return date

def your_function():

    for values in params.values():
        if 'since' in values:
            values['since'] = formatDate(values['since'], dt.datetime.strptime(values['since'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

        if 'until' in values:
            values['until'] = formatDate(values['until'], dt.datetime.strptime(y['until'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

        if 'start_date' in values:
            values['start_date'] = formatDate(values['start_date'], dt.datetime.strptime(values['start_date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

        if 'end_date' in values:
            values['end_date'] = formatDate(values['end_date'], dt.datetime.strptime(values['end_date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Code not tested, but I would extract the common logic to a function and have only one foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over a nested dict after you load json, you need to use object_hook method of json.loads() to deserialize dates on import (I assume you're using built-in json library to parse json).

This has already been answered, please have a look at this thread:
[How to convert to a Python datetime object with JSON.loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793448/how-to-convert-to-a-python-datetime-object-with-json-loads)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a nested dictionary comprehension and a dict mapping function for time conversion:

```
def time_conversion(arg):
    switcher = {
        'today': datetime.now(),
        'yesterday': datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
    }

    output = (datetime.strptime(arg, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
                  if arg not in switcher.keys() else switcher.get(arg))
    return output


new_params = {outer_k:{inner_k: time_conversion(inner_v) 
                          if inner_k in ('since', 'until', 'date_preset') else inner_v 
                       for inner_k, inner_v in outer_v.items()} 
              for outer_k, outer_v in params.items()}
```