# Validating JSON Schema with Cerberus throws error when using correct data type

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, cerberus

I am trying to validate a JSON schema. When specifying the correct data type `date` for `released` Cerberus throws an error.

```
def test_validate_books_schema():
    schema = {
            "url" : {'type': 'string'},
            "name" : {'type': 'string'},
            "isbn" : {'type': 'string'},
            "authors" : {'type': ['string','list']},
            "numberOfPages" : {'type': 'integer'},
            "publisher" : {'type': 'string'},
            "country" : {'type': 'string'},
            "mediaType" : {'type': 'string'},
            "released" : {'type': 'date'},
            "characters" : {'type': ['string','list']},
            "povCharacters" : {'type': ['string','list']}            
        }

    response = requests.get("https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/books/1")
    
    v = Validator(schema)
    validate_response = v.validate(response.json())
    assert_that(validate_response, description=v.errors).is_true()
```

```
./tests/books/test_books.py::test_validate_books_schema Failed: [undefined]AssertionError: [{'released': ['must be of date type']}] Expected <True>, but was not.
def test_validate_books_schema():
        schema = {
                "url" : {'type': 'string'},
                "name" : {'type': 'string'},
                "isbn" : {'type': 'string'},
                "authors" : {'type': ['string','list']},
                "numberOfPages" : {'type': 'integer'},
                "publisher" : {'type': 'string'},
                "country" : {'type': 'string'},
                "mediaType" : {'type': 'string'},
                "released" : {'type': 'date'},
                "characters" : {'type': ['string','list']},
                "povCharacters" : {'type': ['string','list']}
            }
    
        response = requests.get("https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/books/1")
    
        v = Validator(schema)
        validate_response = v.validate(response.json())
>       assert_that(validate_response, description=v.errors).is_true()
E       AssertionError: [{'released': ['must be of date type']}] Expected <True>, but was not.

tests\books\test_books.py:42: AssertionError
```

The [documentation](https://anapioficeandfire.com/Documentation#books) states that the data type for `released` is `Date`. When I specify `string` for `released` it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code just slightly like so:

```py
from cerberus import Validator
from assertpy import assert_that
from datetime import datetime
import requests

def date_hook(json_dict):
    for (key, value) in json_dict.items():
        try:
            json_dict[key] = datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
        except:
            pass
    return json_dict

def test_validate_books_schema():
    schema = {
            "url" : {'type': 'string'},
            "name" : {'type': 'string'},
            "isbn" : {'type': 'string'},
            "authors" : {'type': ['string','list']},
            "numberOfPages" : {'type': 'integer'},
            "publisher" : {'type': 'string'},
            "country" : {'type': 'string'},
            "mediaType" : {'type': 'string'},
            "released" : {'type': 'date'},
            "characters" : {'type': ['string','list']},
            "povCharacters" : {'type': ['string','list']}            
        }

    response = requests.get("https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/books/1")

    v = Validator(schema)
    validate_response = v.validate(response.json(object_hook=date_hook))
    assert_that(validate_response, description=v.errors).is_true()

test_validate_books_schema()
print('Done')
```

What we did here is add an object hook in `response.json` that'll call `date_hook`, which formats date/time appropriately ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793448/how-to-convert-to-a-python-datetime-object-with-json-loads))

Once you run your file, you should not get any error.

Comment: Thank you ! This works great. In regards to the error message is it correct ?

Comment: The error message you were getting (`AssertionError: [{'released': ['must be of date type']}]`) is correct because response.json() was not able to parse 1998-01-01T00:00:00 as date. So, cerberus wasn't able to validate the response. To overcome the issue, we had to ensure that response.json() was reading the datetime correctly. Once we told .json() method to use object hook, which parsed the datetime correctly, .json() had the right datetime and cerberus was able to do validation and your assert_that statement gave desired result.